# How can i add ImageViews next to items in my ListView?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am trying to make a recipe ListView for food and I want to add imageViews next to items in my list. How can i do that? Thx.

Comment: Please Explain your query.. What exactly you want? You want to add new View(Item/Images) in your list...?

Answer (score 0):

A ListView item can have it's own custom layout.

You have to create your adapter for the ListView. When you create your adapter you can assign your custom layout.

Note: You will have to implement getView() to property set the image+text.

Here you have a sample: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

Answer (score 0):

Following this tutorial could be a nice idea for you (mainly the second example).

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

But anyway, you should Google a little bit before asking such a basic question.